# Problem recompiling using make command

Tags: re-installation, c++, c

I'm trying to modify some C++ files in ns2 and then recompile using make command. Although new .o file is created after make, the output is similar to that of previous C++ file (before modifying). Can someone suggest what may be the reason behind it?

Comment: What sort of changes were you making?  A make file is only as good as the dependencies it encodes.  So for example if you were making changes to inlined functions in a header and the files that included it weren't recompiled, then that might explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Try using: `make clean` before `make`. This removes the old .o files and creates new ones. So you completely recompile it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you modifying .cpp (or .C .cc etc.) files or header files? Some Makefiles are written very poorly and don't have decent dependency information (`gcc -MMD` or `makedepend`). This means the project is not rebuild correctly if you modify some files (often header files). You can check what files are triggered by modification (and why) with the command:

```
make --debug=b -n
```